# AndroidX Activity Result API onActivityCreated Deprecated

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, androidx, deprecation-warning

After implementing the below dependency in app level Gradle

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-beta02"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.2.0-beta02"
```

I found the below warning in my fragment in onActivityCreated method

```
Overrides deprecated method in 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment'
```

What might be the new way of implementing this method. Below is my onActivityCreated method

```java
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
}
```

I am using the dependency for requestPermissionLauncher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check out the changelog/deprecation warning here in more detail: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha02

**Specifically**

> The onActivityCreated() method is now deprecated. Code touching the
> fragment's view should be done in onViewCreated() (which is called
> immediately before onActivityCreated()) and other initialization code
> should be in onCreate().

Changing your code to the example below should remove the deprecation warning:

```java
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
}
```